# Continuous Checking for a value Asynchronously Swift 3

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift3, raspberry-pi

I have a button hooked up to a raspberry pi that is running a node server. I am using Socket.IO to interface with said server. The node server works well and when the button is pressed emits to the phone.

Basically all I want to do is have a label in the view that says "Button is Currently Pressed/Button is not Currently Pressed". I want to do this asynchronously in swift, so I can add other features later on that won't interfere with checking that button state. I haven't really found any good leads by google.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think your question is how to implement websockets in Swift.  Please google `swift socket.io client`

Comment: I already have socket io working, with no issue. On the iOS side of things I want to constantly poll the server in the background for changes. Basically I want the button press to be acknowledged at any time by the iOS app. I need the app to be usable, while also polling for changes to the button state.

Comment: Yes, you need a socket.io client, to connect to your socket.io raspberry pi server.  There are open source libraries that handle exactly this on the other side of that search.

Comment: I have all of that connected. The server and the app have no issue talking. What I need to be able to do is this. When the application enters the background I want the app to continue working and when the app comes into the foreground it should be like the app had been open the whole time.